# Using a macbook, is there a way to make it so one key will create an open apostrophe and another will create a closed apostrophe?

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, keyboard

I am "transliterating" Arabic so the apostrophes have nothing to do with apostrophe function. The open apostrophe represents the Arabic letter ع and the closed apostrophe represents the Arabic letter ء.

I am using the ABC extended keyboard in Mac keyboard settings. I can only find one key that represents an apostrophe and that's option+i.

If I type it in this textarea, I see that it makes a closed apostrophe by default ʼʼʼʼʼʼʼʼ.

In word, it autoformats to be an open apostrophe.

I can't find the option to turn off autoformatting here. And if I could, I wouldn't know how to set it so that I could type an open apostrophe.

I did find one solution and that's to just trick word into typing the right apostrophe then delete the unnecessary text...but that's obviously not ideal.

Using mac+word, I want some sort of way to make one key mapping produce an open apostrophe and another to produce a closed one. How can I implement this?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. Do you want a one key approach to add an Arabic character or an English apostrophe character?

Comment: One key for open apostrophe and one key for closed

Comment: What version of Mac Office are you running?

Comment: It says word version 15.28

Answer (score 0):

Before doing anything you need to update your version of Mac Office 2016. If you are running a Retail (Perpetual) version of Office 2016 your version should be 16.16.3, which means your software has not been updated since November 2016.

Most likely you will also need to update the Microsoft Auto Updater (MAU) software and do that update first. Here is a link for the current MAU Download: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=830196

Details for all of the Update History for Mac Office 2016, including download links are contained here: [Update History for Mac Office](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-office-for-mac?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fUpdate-history-for-Office-2016-for-Mac-700cab62-0d67-4f23-947b-3686cb1a8eb7#bkmk_history)

Comment: Okay, I've updated it to 16.16.3!

Comment: @NickManning, If you press the single apostrophe key in a new blank document, what to you get? If you then enter a blank space followed by the single apostrophe key, what do you get? If you could take a screen clip of the result and put that into your initial question, that would be helpful.